# Shorter link urls in Wicket

Tags: performance, url, wicket, wicket-1.6

I am creating an application with a lot of links. Because the links are contained in cells in a table, the urls that are generated by Wicket tend to get long, making the page slower to load.

For example:

```
 <a href="./?0-2.ILinkListener-f-t-body-rows-11-cells-2-cell-li-35-link">2011-06-09 00:00:00.0</a>
```

I try to figure out where to start exploring the encoding / decoding of URLs, but it is rather complex material. My first approach was to just use 'short' names for components (like "t", "f" etc). I can imagine there is a better approach.

I can image it would be possible just to 'number' the links; as the page still exists, so I would end up with something like this:

```
 <a href="./?0-2.ILinkListener-1237">2011-06-09 00:00:00.0</a>
```

Are there solutions for my problem already out there, or can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a Javascript solution is acceptable, you can use a single event listener on the whole table instead of many links in the table.

See this example for an inspiration:

https://github.com/svenmeier/apachecon-wicket/tree/master/src/main/java/eu/apachecon/base/ui/performance

Notice how the Ajax behavior transports dynamic extra parameters to the server. It looks for rows only though. if you need to distinguish between table *cells* being clicked, you'll have to expand on the idea.

Comment: Mmm. Seems like a workaround that might work. I was hoping for a more fundamental solution though.

Comment: I created a more generic solution, based on your solution. See: https://github.com/RobAu/wicket-jq-autocomplete/tree/master/jq-autocomplete/src/main/java/org/audenaerde/onchildeventbehavior

Answer (score 0):

The solution suggested by Sven is the better solution.

Here is a solution which you may call fundamental: register your own root IRequestMapper that will compress/uncompress the generated urls by the real mappers. See CryptoMapper and HttpsMapper for example of custom root mapper.